# How to re-order shortcuts using installshield quickpatch

Tags: installshield-2012

We have quickpatch project(InstallShield 2012) for our minor product update. It is based on existing MSI package.

The installed product has shortcuts undeer start menu -> all programs in following order:
[Product Folder]
    [Program Shortcut1]
    [Product Subfolder]

Other program shortcuts are placed under [Product Subfolder].
Now, through this patch we want to move [Program Shortcut1] under [Product Subfolder].

Is this possible using quickpatch, and if yes, how can we do it? 
Any help on this will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the order of sibling items within a single folder, or moving items from one folder to within a subfolder? The former isn't something MSI offers control over.

Comment: Yes Michael, I want to move item into a sub-folder. These shortcuts under are created by earlier installed product. I want my patch to move one of such shortcuts one folder level under.